# How To convert free android app into paid app

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle application upgrades from free to paid version while preserving any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011164/how-to-handle-application-upgrades-from-free-to-paid-version-while-preserving-an)

I want to have a free version and a premium version of the same application. When people buy the application, I want them to be able to "upgrade" without losing their data, i.e. the premium version should install over the free version.

Comment: have a look at, http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this would be to make use of Google Play's In-App billing. So your app will contain all the code for the full version, but is limited to the free version until they pay for the in-app purchase.